# modeling Unordered Set in ANTLR4 lexer

Tags: antlr4

how to model an (unordered) set of 'things' within { }.
Each thing may occur only once, or not at all.  Sequence of occurrence in the set is random.  e.g. `set { a, b, c }`  OR `set { c, b }`.  how to model this in the lexer for antlr4?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the *lexer* for this at all. To validate this in a parser, I would use a rule like the following:

```
set
  : 'set' '{'
    ( a
    | b
    | c
    )*
    '}'
  ;
```

I would then create parse tree listener or visitor to validate the [0-1] constraint. The argument to the method is a `SetContext ctx`.

```
if (ctx.a().size() > 1)
  myReportErrorMethod("set can only contain one 'a' item");
if (ctx.b().size() > 1)
  myReportErrorMethod("set can only contain one 'b' item");
if (ctx.c().size() > 1)
  myReportErrorMethod("set can only contain one 'c' item");
```

Comment: excellent.  I was struggling to find out how to restrict number of occurrences within the grammar - lexer or parser.  But the code in the listener above, makes sense!!  Thank you.  That answers my question.